# Login / register error with username / password combination PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following a tutorial on phpacademy to login and register. 
I followed the scripts on Youtube. In the 3th part everything is going well untill te last part of the functions. If I enter the username and password that are also in te database I get the message: Array ( [0] => That username/password

Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong please? 
This is so far my login part:

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';



if (empty($_POST) === false) { 
    $username = $_POST['username']; 
    $password = $_POST['password']; 

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password'; 
    } else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
    } else if (user_active($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account!';
    } else {
        $login = login($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect';

    } else {
        echo 'ok!';

}
}
}
?>
```

And this is my users part where (i think) the last part is going wrong.

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function user_id_from_email($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
?>
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the password for that user has been `hashed` with MD5 before it was stored?

Comment: Please, take a good advice: close a tab with this site of whatever "phpacademy" in your browser and **never ever navigate to it again**

Comment: Anyway, "please tell mr whats wrong with my code" questions are offtopic here

Comment: I am not expert but it seems to me that your queries are wrong. For example; "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'" , in this query, $username is concatenated with . to the string. To me it should be like that : "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = `' .$username '`"

Comment: @ RiggsFolly : I did it while setting up a test account in the database.

Comment: @ B.K. i am a beginner with php. When I put a . before $usernam for example i get : Array ( [0] => We can't find that username. Have you registered? )

Comment: @Sylvie could you change the query of user_exists as return (mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(` user_id ` ) FROM ` users ` WHERE ` username ` = '.$username.'`'), 0) == 1) ? true : false; If this works, change others like that.

Edit: I added a blank between ` and other characters because of the stackoverflow tag system. You may need to delete those blanks

Comment: That won't matter. A double-quoted string will expand the variable.
`$a = "hello";`
`echo "$a world"` vs `echo $a . " world"` will have the same result

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox actually what I want him to do is to concatenate $username to the string. In php . is used for this, I think.

Comment: @B.K. The dot operator is for concatenation, but in a double-quoted string internal variables are expanded, so changing it as you mentioned would give the same result.

Comment: @Sylvie for a sanity check, have it echo the query string, then connect to the database directly and copy and paste that string in. Does it return anything?

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox ok forget about double-quoted :) if you look at the fourth command, I typed the query wrong. I also forgot to putting dot operator after the $username. And if you look at my later commands, I added 2 dot operators at the beginning and end of $username. You are right double quoted will not change anything but my priority is dot operator. I want him to try it. As I said before I am not expert on PHP :)

Comment: @ B.K. It changes nothing. But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox Everything works until I put the this part init: function user_id_from_email($email) {
 $email = sanitize($email);
 return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function login($username, $password) {
 $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
 
 $username = sanitize($username);
 $password = md5($password);
 
 return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
?>

Comment: If I delete this : function login($username, $password) {
 $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
 
 $username = sanitize($username);
 $password = md5($password);
 
 return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '.$username.' AND `password` = '.$password.'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}                                                                   I get a blanc document , so he doesn't print the ok set in the login.php file